# Access specifier for float does not behave as expected

Tags: floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f",5);
}
```

This code is printing 0.000000. Can anyone explain why this is happening.

Comment: Because you display int as double - this is definition how many place after comma you want display- take a look how to display double/float by printf() method in google :)

Comment: Did your compiler not warn you about the `%f`-int mismatch?

Comment: try investigating yourself.. say for ex., ["%f",5.0] ["%f", .5] ["%.5f", 5]["%.5f",5.0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in your example, `5` is an integer, not a float. Thus, when you pass it to `printf` with the formatting string of `%f`, you get undefined behavior. To make it a float, declare it with the floating point (`5.0`). This will give you your expected output.

## Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f", 5.0);
}
```

## Outputs:

```
5.000000
```

Answer (score 5):

The `%f` format expects a `double` argument, you are passing an `int`. This is undefined behavior and anything can happen. You are lucky that what happened was only the printing of 0.00000.

In C, variadic functions do not know the types of the arguments that have been passed to them at the call site. In the case of `printf`, they can only trust the format string to provide that information. Any good compiler should warn if the types of the arguments do not match the (known at compile-time) format string, and I am surprised that yours did not. The function's implementation can rely on *default argument promotions* having been applied, but that is all.

In practice, two common cases are that arguments are passed on the stack, in which case the `int` value `5` that was pushed at the call site will be interpreted as a 64-bit `double`, or arguments are passed through registers, in which case the `printf` function will get a `double` value from the floating-point register that was not set at the call site and contains whichever value was left there last time it was used.

Answer (score 3):

This is called undefined behavior because "%f" expects a float or double, yet you gave it the integer `5`.

Undefined behavior means that the compiler can do just about anything that is legal to deal with the situation.

To solve, you have three options:

1. `printf("%i", 5)`
2. `printf("%f", 5.0)`
3. `printf("%f", (double) 5)`

Answer (score 2):

`%f` is the format specifier for the `double` type (or `float`, which gets automatically promoted to `double` in variable-argument lists), but you're passing it an `int`. As other answerers have correctly pointed out, this is undefined behavior.

But why is the output *zero* instead of some *other* garbage value?  This requires a little knowledge of the most common [floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

What's most-likely happening is that your (probably) 32-bit `int` value is getting zero-extended to a 64-bit `double` value in such a way that these extra 32 zero bits fill the sign bit, the 11-bit exponent, and the first 20 bits of the significand.  This results in a [denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) value that is so close to zero that the fixed-point `%f` format rounds it to `0.00000`.  Using the `%e` or `%g` format instead would likely have displayed a small but non-zero value.

Again, this is just an implementation detail, and a different C implementation may give a different output, or cause a segmentation fault.

What you probably *meant* to write is either

- `printf("%f", 5.0)` (using the correct data type for the `%f` format), or
- `printf("%d", 5)` (using the correct format string for the `int` type)

To prevent *accidental* use of mismatched `printf` calls like `printf("%f", 5)`, enable compiler warnings (e.g. use the `-Wall` option with GCC), and pay attention to them when you compile your programs.

Comment: zero-extension does not happen with the common IA-32 ABIs (32 bits are pushed, 64 bits are read, there is no zero-extension), and it does not happen with the common x86-64 ABIs (the first floating-point argument is obtained from `xmm0`), so I am not sure what your point it.